# How to fix 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)' when trying to implement Factory Pattern

Tags: c++, object, pointers, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I'm trying to implement the factory pattern in my code.

I tried to create an object "Koerper schienbein" and initialized it with

```
schienbein.setRadius(0.2);
schienbein.setLaenge(1.0);
schienbein.setPosition(0, 0, 1.0);
schienbein.erzeugeBody(world);
```

Therefore I'm assuming that there is no error within the class "Koerper".

This is my code for my factories.

Koerperfabrik.h:

```
class Koerperfabrik {

public:
    Koerper *erzeugeKoerperteil(dWorldID welt);

protected:
    virtual Koerper *erzeugeKoerper(dWorldID welt) { };

};
```

Koerperfabrik.cpp:

```
Koerper *Koerperfabrik::erzeugeKoerperteil(dWorldID welt) {
    Koerper *koerper = new Koerper ();
    koerper = erzeugeKoerper(welt);

    return koerper;
}
```

Schienbeinfabrik.cpp:

```
Koerper *Schienbeinfabrik :: erzeugeKoerper(dWorldID welt) {
    Koerper* schienbein = new Koerper ();
    (*schienbein).setRadius(0.2);
    (*schienbein).setLaenge(1.0);
    (*schienbein).setPosition(0, 0, 1.0);
    (*schienbein).erzeugeBody(welt);

    return schienbein;
}
```

Simulation.cpp:

```
void erzeugeFussundSchienbein() {
    Koerperfabrik schienbeinfabrik = Schienbeinfabrik ();
    schienbein = schienbeinfabrik.erzeugeKoerperteil(world);
}
```

When I try to access (*schienbein).getBody() I get the error "Speicherzugriffsfehler (Speicherabzug geschrieben)" which translates to "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

I hope there is somebody who can help me.

Comment: In `Koerperfabrik::erzeugeKoerperteil` you create a `Koerper` on the heap, and then immidiately lose that object *forever*, because you overwrite the pointer to it with result of `erzeugeKoerper`

Comment: Translating it to english would help non-german readers to understand your code. In addition to @Yksisarvinen comment: ```Koerperfabrik schienbeinfabrik = Schienbeinfabrik ();``` - this is not what you probably intended to do, but since there is no definition of ```Schienbeinfabrik``` here, I can't tell for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You have undefined behavior.

This class has a function that should return something, yet doesn't:

```
class Koerperfabrik {

public:
    Koerper *erzeugeKoerperteil(dWorldID welt);

protected:
    //    A return type                     no return value
    //      ~~~v~~~                                ~v~
    virtual Koerper* erzeugeKoerper(dWorldID welt) { };

};
```

You really should enable warnings, since warnings you have warned you for that. Here's a [godbolt example of the warning](https://godbolt.org/z/OzwpnI). On that example I enabled `-Werror` to stop the compilation on warning, but this is optional.

I assume you wanted to create a pure virtual fonction.

---

In the code on your main function, you never call `Schienbeinfabrik`:

```
//   You care creating a new Koerperfabrik
//         |        Here you copy a Schienbeinfabrik into it
//  v-------------v               ~~~~~~~~~v~~~~~~~~~ 
Koerperfabrik schienbeinfabrik = Schienbeinfabrik ();
schienbein = schienbeinfabrik.erzeugeKoerperteil(world);
```

The variable `schienbeinfabrik` is always of the type `Koerperfabrik`, which is not what you intended. You should instead do that:

```
// construct a new Schienbeinfabrik
Schienbeinfabrik schienbeinfabrik;

// call something on it
schienbein = schienbeinfabrik.erzeugeKoerperteil(world);
```

Objects are never null in C++, so there's no error there. The factory is implicitly constructed using the default constructor.

---

Lastly, you have memory leak:

```
Koerper *Koerperfabrik::erzeugeKoerperteil(dWorldID welt) {
    Koerper *koerper = new Koerper (); // a new Koerper

    // You reassign the pointer, you loose
    // reference to the previous koerper
    koerper = erzeugeKoerper(welt);

    return koerper;
}
```

Just remove the new:

```
Koerper* koerper = erzeugeKoerper(welt);
```